# Set an array using a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi i want to be able to extract data from an array, while setting it using a variable.
Like this:

```
var x = ("a","b","c","d");

var z = new Array(x);
```

This won't work, as when doing this:

```
alert(z[0]);
```

or anything like that (other integers etc.) it will not work.
It will simply display the entire array instead of actually showing the text at the given place. Setting an array by doing this though:

```
var z = new Array("a","b","c","d");
```

will make it work and when taking z[0], it will actually show the correct text. 
The reason i want to do this is because i want to be able to set an array by using what is typed into an input.

Does someone know how to make this work since i have no idea why it is not working right now. It seems pretty logical that it should actually work.

Comment: Stop using the new keyword and do : `var z = x[0];` and arrays are created with `["a","b","c","d"]`

Comment: `var chars = "input string".split('');`

Comment: The new Array() constructor takes arrayLength as it's only argument: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code will result in an array with a single element (that element will contain "d") since what you actually have is a (pointless) grouping operator and a bunch of comma operators. The comma operator simply returns the final operand (in this case, the string "d").

```
console.log(z); // "['d']"
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I think you want this (since by the sound of it you're starting with a string of user input):

```
var x = "a,b,c,d";
var z = x.split(",");

// or

var x = "abcd";
var z = x.split(""); // Empty string, splits between every char
```

Now `z` will contain an array with 4 elements, like you expect.

Comment: Thanks this is indeed what i was looking for, i wanted a user to input the text and make an array using it. The others probbly thought i didn't know how to make an array.

Answer (score 4):

The following statement:

```
var x = ("a","b","c","d");
```

Is not an array declaration.  You should use square brackets:

```
var x = ["a","b","c","d"];
```

I personally never use the "Array" function when writing javascript.  Instead I just use square brackets:

```
var emptyArray = [];
var arrayWithItems = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = ("a","b","c","d");
```

This creates a `string` variable x of value "d".

```
var z = new Array(x);
```

This creates a single element array with just one string of value "d".

You should declare arrays in the following syntax.

```
var x = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
console.error(x[0]); // will echo "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the array declaration to :

```
 var x = ["a","b","c","d"];
```

alert(x[0]) in this case displays `a`

Answer (score 0):

You missed `Array` in `var x = ("a","b","c","d");` statement

The above will `return d` always which is `element` in `braces`

Use it like `var x = Array("a","b","c","d");`